# Does using MongoDB stitch also charges costs for MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I've been looking around for so many days over the internet, but couldn't find an answer.

I'm building an educational app where students can search questions for different subjects and grades. There are over **40k** questions as of yet and the question bank is growing. Currently, I'm serving these questions through mySQL database, but I want to use a document-based database (MongoDB, Firestore etc.)

Considering **50k** document reads/day and **20k** writes/day, firestore comes out to be an expensive choice for this question-bank system.

Coming to MongoDB Atlas, it offers free cluster but due to limited number of concurrent connections (100 for free cluster), I cannot use it. Even M5 cluster has just 100 available concurrent connections.

Finally comes the MongoDB stitch, its pricing structure looks good but as MongoDB stitch requires connection to a MongoDB Atlas Cluster, so two questions come up in my mind.

- Will I be charged for both services separately (for MongoDB Atlas Cluster pricing, as well as MongoDB stitch pricing)?
- If I use a free MongoDB Atlas Cluster, will it affect performance of MongoDB stitch app as the users of my app grow?

If the answer is yes to both or any of the above questions, then I think using MongoDB this way is very expensive and I'll have to look for some other options. Please suggest if there is a better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Coming to MongoDB Atlas, it offers free cluster but due to limited number of concurrent connections (100 for free cluster), I cannot use it. Even M5 cluster has just 100 available concurrent connections.**

How many concurrent connection you need? One of my app with 5000-6000 daily users and in my peak I only used up to 10 concurrent locations.

---

**Will I be charged for both services separately (for MongoDB Atlas Cluster pricing, as well as MongoDB stitch pricing)?**

Yes. Pricing for both are separated. Stitch is calculated based on your computing time and Atlas is charged for bandwidth and space, cpu and memory of your database.

**If I use a free MongoDB Atlas Cluster, will it affect performance of MongoDB stitch app as the users of my app grow?**

The performance of Stitch and Mongodb Atlas is independent of each other.

**Tip:**

One of the the reason for slowness in your app is directly affected by the location of your Atlas server location. Stitch is only located in 4 locations at the moment - US. East, US.West, Ireland (EU) and Sydney (AU).

If you want to optimise the response rate of your stitch functions, it's important that you create the atlas free database at **the exact same location** as your stitch deployment location.

**For example**, my users are located in Singapore, so naturally I will create my Atlas on AWS Singapore, and my Stitch deployment location in Sydney (AU).

I realise very slow performance on this because this is roughly what happens on the backend.

- **Client in Singapore calls serverless function**
- **Stitch in Sydney connects Singapore database server** ( I understand mongodb has edge service, but somehow this is happening since your data may not be readily available in the edge point )
- **Stitch in Sydney retrieves the data, process the data and returns to my Singapore client.**

In the process, data was transmitted from Singapore > Au > Singapore > Au > Singapore and that was a lot fo overhead!

I was experiencing 900ms to 2-3 seconds of response time for a function call, and once I changed my atlas cluster to AWS Sydney, my response time is now 150-300ms.

Making this change also reduces the Stitch serverless function computing time and hence lower cost in the long run.

**In Addition**

- Stitch is easier to use than AWS Lamda if you are just working on
  your codes and MongoDB and you do not require all the AWS services.
  You can spin up a working app with Authentication in just 10 minutes
  since Stitch takes care of all the authentication/session etc for
  you.
- They can host your static files! (e.g React build files) so you do
  not need to create another s3 bucket to host them.
- Static hosting means you have serverless functions, database, and
  your Single Page App all in one service ready to be deployed.

**Conclusion**
Stitch free tier and Atlas free tier performance in my opinion is fast enough to deploy any app. Stitch's serverless feature also means you do not need to worry about scaling. If the atlas free tier is good enough for you, then you are ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes The atlas and stitch usage fees are charged separately.
2. According to pricing, stitch execution performance will not affect itself, but free atlas clusters are slow. By itself, stitch functions can be slow to respond.